# GET data from website and put it at google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping, google-sheets

I know there is quite decent amount of topics about this, but I couldn't find any that seems to be working for me. I want to post some of the variables on google spreadsheet obtained by another website.

I have some variables like:

```
var a = parseInt($('table.thinline:eq(4)>tbody>tr:eq(1)>td:eq(1)').text().replace(/\D/g,''),10);
var b = $('table.thinline:eq(0)>tbody>tr:eq(1)>td:eq(1)').text();
var c = parseInt($('table.thinline:eq(3)>tbody>tr:eq(2)>td:eq(1)').text().replace(/\D/g,''),10);
```

As soon as the page is being loaded, I want them to be posted on google spreadsheet in columns. So first column should pick values that are stored under variable a, second column - var b, third column - var c etc.

I'd also like to avoid forms.

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to fill in your variables at the bottom of three individual rows of a Google Sheet.

This can be achieved with the .appendRow method. You'll find the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)).

```js
var spreadSheetID = ""; // Add string with the ID of your spreadsheet here
var sheetName = ""; // Add string with the name of your Sheet here
var a = "value for first column";
var b = "value for second column";
var c = "value for third column";

function appendRows() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadSheetID); // Select Spreadsheet by ID
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Select your Sheet by its Name

  sheet.appendRow([a, b, c]);
}

appendRows();
```

This appends a to row A, b to row B and c to row C.